# java.lang.IllegalStateException: recyclerview_latestmessage must not be null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

hope you're doing well.
I'm developing an android with fragment use and I have some problems.
I implement a recycler view in a fragment layout an I initialize it. 
But when I run the code, the logcat show this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: recyclerview_latestmessage must not be null
The id of the recycler view is : recyclerview_latestmessage
I use a bundle call groupie to replace the RecyclerView adapter. You can find more information here: https://github.com/lisawray/groupie#groupie

Here is my code.

**fragment_chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ChatFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_latestmessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_new_message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_new_message"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ChatFragment**

```
package com.example.noalumni.fragments

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_chat.*
import com.example.noalumni.R
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.noalumni.activities.ChatLogActivity
import com.example.noalumni.activities.LatestMessageRow
import com.example.noalumni.activities.NewMessageActivity
import com.example.noalumni.model.Message
import com.example.noalumni.model.Users
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder


class ChatFragment : Fragment() {


    companion object{
        var currentUser: Users? = null
        val TAG = "LatestMessages"
    }

    private lateinit var _view: View
    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
    lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)

        recyclerView = _view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_latestmessage)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerview_latestmessage.adapter= adapter
        recyclerview_latestmessage.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))

        val new_message = _view.findViewById(R.id.button_new_message) as Button
        new_message.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity, NewMessageActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return _view
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I just don't understand why are you changing the name of your recyclerview suddenly.

```
recyclerView = _view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_latestmessage)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recyclerView.adapter= adapter
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
```

just use these lines of code and the rest of the code looks perfectly alright so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `findViewById<RecyclerView>(..)!!`, because the function findViewById return a `@Nullable` type.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, `findViewById` return the `@Nullable` type, so declare your `Recycler` to nullable like `var recyclerView : RecyclerView? = null`.

Comment: Or you can use `findViewById(...)!!` to make sure it not null.